# How to except coma in search word in RegExp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have string:

```
const text = 'A Jack# Jack#aNyWord Jack, Jack';
```

i want search word "Jack" only, but if Jack contain # character, its say true mean match.

i try like:

```
const text = 'A Jack# Jack#aNyWord Jack, Jack';
const regexpWords = /Jack(?=,|#)/g;
console.log(text.match(regexpWords));
```

result say: `Array ["Jack", "Jack", "Jack"]`

My expected output is: `Array ["Jack#", "Jack#aNyWord", "Jack", "Jack"]`

except word "Jack,"

how can i do with this

Comment: i mean like this still ok for me ["Jack#", "Jack#aNyWord", "Jack", "Jack"]  
T.J. Crowder
how can i do that?

Comment: i has edit my quetion

Comment: Just FYI re *"How to except coma..."* If you meant *comma*, `#` isn't a comma, it's a hash symbol / number sign. This is a comma: `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `#` **in** the match, then you don't want a lookahead (`(?=___)`) because lookahead and lookbehind aren't included in matches. You haven't said what should be valid following the `#`, but if I assume any letter or number, then:

```js
const text = "A Jack# Jack#aNyWord Jack, Jack";
const regexpWords = /Jack(?:#[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/g;
console.log(text.match(regexpWords));
```

That says

- Match `Jack`
- *Optionally* match `#` followed by any number of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. I do that by wrapping `#[a-zA-Z0-9]*` in a non-capturing group (`(?:___)`) and then making the group optional with `?`

I've used `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` for the letters following the `#` because the expression doesn't have the `i` flag (case-insensitive matching, would match `jack`). You could use `[a-z0-9]*` if you're going to add the `i` flag. (You might also use `\w`, but it allows `_` which you may or may not want.)

MDN's regular expressions documentation is quite good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder, you save my day, that what i looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the words with Jack and there must be at least `Jack#` you can match the part of the string containing Jack# using a negated character class `[^,\n]*` excluding matching comma's or newlines.

If there is a match, then split the match on one or more whitspace characters and filter the result containing the word Jack using word boundaries `\b`

```js
const text = 'A Jack# Jack#aNyWord Jack, Jack';
const regexpWords = /[^,\n]*\bJack#[^,\n]*/g;
const m = text.match(regexpWords);

if (m) {
  const result = m[0]
    .split(/\s+/)
    .filter(s => s.match(/\bJack\b/));

  console.log(result);
}
```

After the question was updated, if Jack should be at the beginning of the word:

```
(?<!\S)Jack(?:#[^\s,]*)?
```

(or use `\bJack` to prevent a partial word match)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRyUV5/1) for the matches.